# Android viewPager onPageSelected can't get correct database id with respect to viewPager position

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, ormlite

I have created the module for loading database record with id=1,2,3,4,5,... by getting the position of the viewPage Swiped as position index +1 . It has been implemented in    OnPageChangeListener onPageSelected method. When it comes to the testing, it shows that the index shows zero at the beginning as 0,2,3,4 instead of index 1,2,3,4 ..to load the record. When I swipe right , it loads another same record instead of none, even setting setOffscreenPageLimit as zero. I don't want this to happen

Would you please tell me the alternative to read the position of the viewPager page ?

The below is my working :

```
    mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setEnabled(true);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);



OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {      
            pageId = position + 1;
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            final Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FlightBankActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
            for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {               
                dots[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_e);
            }
            dots[position].setAnimation(animationFadeIn);
            dots[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_s);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            ArrayList<FlightProfile> fpList = (ArrayList<FlightProfile>) DatabaseManager.getInstance().getAllFlightProfile();
            System.out.println(fpList.size() + " : is the size of profile");
            for(FlightProfile gfg : fpList){
                System.out.println(gfg.getId()+ " is the profile id");
                System.out.println(gfg.getName()+ " is the profile i]name");
            }
            System.out.println(pageId+ " : is the pageId");  
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };
```

Fragment.java

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 
            final int type = bundle.getInt("type");
            System.out.println("type :" + type); 

            fp = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getFlightProfile(pageId);    

...
```